# How to set Android Chip text appearance from currently selected Main App Theme

Tags: android, android-theme

I have been investigating dynamically changing my Android Apps theme in my current Android project.

I have defined a base Theme then created multiple sub themes which simply employ a different font.

This all works fine and as expected for TextViews.

```
<style name="Theme.MyBaseTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/WindowAnimations</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/primaryVariantColor</item>
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/secondaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/secondaryVariantColor</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceLarge">@style/TextAppearance.Literal</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/roboto_regular</item>
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/roboto_regular</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.MyBaseTheme.Readable" parent="Theme.MyBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/lexie_readable_regular</item>
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/lexie_readable_regular</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.MyBaseTheme.Dyslexic" parent="Theme.MyBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/open_dyslexic_regular</item>
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/open_dyslexic_regular</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.MyBaseTheme.Mono" parent="Theme.MyBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/b612_mono_regular</item>
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/b612_mono_regular</item>
</style>
```

I have an issue with the text displayed within `com.google.android.material.chip.Chip`.

namely the `Chip` text appearance does not change.

I can change the `Chip` theme using a custom theme defined as follows

```
<style name="ChipTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Chip">
  <item name="fontFamily">@font/roboto_mono</item>
  <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/roboto_mono</item>
</style>
```

However I cannot see how I can how to link my custom chip theme to my App theme so that when I switch the App theme dynamically the `Chip` text appearance also changes to employ the correct font.

What do I need to do to dynamically switch my App theme and my `Chip` text appearance?

Comment: See also https://m2.material.io/components/chips/android#theming-chips, https://www.gsrikar.com/2020/03/how-to-change-material-chip-text-size.html.

Answer (score 1):

To link your Custom Chip Text Appearance to the base application theme or a sub theme you can use the **"chipStyle"** attribute in your theme.

Change your structure to be like below for your **Base App theme**:

```
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.MyBaseTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
     <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
     <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/roboto_regular</item>
     <item name="fontFamily">@font/roboto_regular</item>
     <item name="chipStyle">@style/ChipStyle.Base</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ChipStyle.Base" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Action">
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/ChipTextAppearance.Base</item>
        <item name="chipBackgroundColor">@android:color/holo_blue_light</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ChipTextAppearance.Base" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Chip">
        <item name="fontFamily">@font/roboto_regular</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/roboto_regular</item>
    </style>
```

Sample of your **Sub theme Readable (Mode)** will be like below:

```
   <!-- Sub theme Readable -->
    <style name="Theme.MyBaseTheme.Readable" parent="Theme.MyBaseTheme">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/lexie_readable_regular</item>
        <item name="fontFamily">@font/lexie_readable_regular</item>
        <item name="chipStyle">@style/ChipStyle.Readable</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ChipStyle.Readable" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Action">
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/ChipTextAppearance.Readable</item>
        <item name="chipBackgroundColor">@android:color/holo_orange_dark</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ChipTextAppearance.Readable" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Chip">
        <item name="fontFamily">@font/lexie_readable_regular</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/lexie_readable_regular</item>
    </style>
```

And you can **use** the above Theme in your Chip like below:

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MyBaseTheme.Readable"
    android:id="@+id/chip"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Chip"/>
```